Container inside of TextFormField Flutter
I have a TextFormField and a DropDown. The user should be able to type in the TextFormField, however, when he clicks on a value of the dropdown, the text from the dropdown should be placed in a container where the cursor of the TextFormField is or if the cursor is not active, the container should be placed at the end of the text. Also, the user should be able to continue writing after the container. I am attaching an image of the desired outcome.
Desired outcome
This is what I tried but I it does not work as expected since the container is added as a prefix of the TextFormField.
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:taginput_example/home_page.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

The main page that uses the custom widget
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:taginput_example/widgets/multiselect.dart';

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});
  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List<String> selectedItems = [];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: SizedBox(
          width: 800,
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20),
                child: DropdownButtonFormField<int>(
                  isExpanded: true,
                  items: List.generate(8, (index) => index).map((int number) {
                    return DropdownMenuItem(
                      value: number,
                      child: Text(
                        number.toString(),
                      ),
                    );
                  }).toList(),
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    setState(() {
                      selectedItems.add(value.toString());
                    });
                  },
                ),
              ),
              Multiselect<String>(
                selected: selectedItems,
                onDeleted: (entry) {
                  setState(() {
                    selectedItems.removeWhere((e) => e == entry);
                  });
                },
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Here is the widget:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Multiselect<T> extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<T> selected;
  final String Function(BuildContext context, T entry)? labelBuilder;
  final Function(T entry)? onDeleted;
  final Function(T entry)? onSelected;
  final String? hint;

  const Multiselect(
      {super.key,
      required this.selected,
      this.labelBuilder,
      this.onDeleted,
      this.onSelected,
      this.hint});

  @override
  State<Multiselect<T>> createState() => _MultiselectState<T>();
}

class _MultiselectState<T> extends State<Multiselect<T>> {
  final FocusNode _focusNode = FocusNode();
  final LayerLink _layerLink = LayerLink();
  final TextEditingController _searchController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _searchController.dispose();

    super.dispose();
  }

  List<Widget> _buildSelectedItems() {
    return widget.selected.map((e) {
      String label = e.toString();
      if (widget.labelBuilder != null) {
        label = widget.labelBuilder!(context, e);
      }

      return Wrap(
        // mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          SizedBox(
            width: 50,
            child: TextField(
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                border: InputBorder.none,
                isDense: true, // Reduces the height of the TextField
                contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8),
              ),
              style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
              onSubmitted: (value) {
                // Handle text field submission
              },
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Theme.of(context).primaryColorDark,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(90),
            ),
            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 5),
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5, horizontal: 10),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: [
                Text(label,
                    style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 16, color: Colors.white)),
                const SizedBox(width: 5),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 20,
                  height: 20,
                  child: FloatingActionButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      if (widget.onDeleted != null) {
                        widget.onDeleted!(e);
                      }
                    },
                    backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent,
                    mini: true,
                    child: const Icon(
                      Icons.close,
                      color: Colors.white,
                      size: 10,
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
          // Adding a text field between the items
          SizedBox(
            width: 50,
            child: TextField(
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                border: InputBorder.none,
                isDense: true, // Reduces the height of the TextField
                contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8),
              ),
              style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
              onSubmitted: (value) {
                // Handle text field submission
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      );
    }).toList();
  }

  Widget? _buildSearchPrefix() {
    if (widget.selected.isEmpty) {
      return null;
    }

    return Wrap(
      crossAxisAlignment: WrapCrossAlignment.center,
      runAlignment: WrapAlignment.center,
      children: [
        ..._buildSelectedItems(),
        const SizedBox(width: 50),
        SizedBox(
          width: 50, // Set the width of the last text field as per your need
          child: TextField(
            decoration: const InputDecoration(
              border: InputBorder.none,
              isDense: true, // Reduces the height of the TextField
              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8),
            ),
            style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
            onSubmitted: (value) {
              // Handle text field submission
            },
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CompositedTransformTarget(
      link: _layerLink,
      child: TextFormField(
        controller: _searchController,
        focusNode: _focusNode,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          hintText: widget.hint,
          prefixIcon: _buildSearchPrefix(),
          hintStyle: TextStyle(
            color: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodySmall!.color,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


You can use textfield_tags package for this here is the minimum working code:
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
    const MyWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

    final _stringTagController = StringTagController();

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return TextFieldTags<String>(
        textfieldTagsController: _stringTagController,
        initialTags:['python','java'],
        textSeparators: const [' ', ','],
        validator: (String tag){
          if (tag == 'php'){
            return 'Php not allowed';
          }
          return null;
        },
        inputFieldBuilder: (context, inputFieldValues){
          return TextField(
            controller: inputFieldValues.textEditingController,
            focusNode: inputFieldValues.focusNode, 
          );
        }
      );
    }
  }

read more about it on pub.dev

Thank you for your response but unfortunately it does not work for my scenario. When I type in the input field, it adds a tag. In my case, the user should be able to type some text, add a tag from the dropdown and then be able to add more text after the tag(s). Please, check the image in my initial question.
